# install jshint globally with npm - config file location

Tags: javascript, node.js, jshint

i've installed jshint using `npm install -g jshint` and i want to know where is the `.jshintrc` file is located - the default location for that file.

I have go through the docs: http://jshint.com/docs/ and i saw the paragraph about where it search for that file. but runnig `find . -name .jshintrc` in my home directory only find rc files that are in `node_modules` directories, so i don't understand where `jshint` get his configuration from.

I also searched the `/usr/lib/node_modules/jshint` - this is where the jshint is installed globally and no luck there , can anyone point me to that information??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know no file is added by installing jshint (example linked below). **Normally, you would put the “.jshintrc” in the source code  root for the project.** This way it’s easily discoverable by others. Then each project applies it’s own set of rules. These kind of files typically applies recursively in the folders below.

But they can be put deeper in folder structure as well. This could be useful in cases where backend and clients use different rules, or when backend is written in another programming language.

Here is an example of such a file:
https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc

Best of luck.